# Android Rating bar Stops OnClickListener for list item

Tags: android, xml, listview, listitem, ratingbar

I currently have a listview in which each item can be clicked to display more info about the list item. I want to add a RatingBar for each list item. Ideally i would like to be able to change the value of the rating bar by clicks and touches. I realize that similar questions have been asked before but i have tried the solutions offered in them. In the xml for the rating bar i have

```
    android:focusable = "false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode = "false"
    android:clickable = "false"
    android:isIndicator = "true"
```

So basically my question is, is it possible to keep the list item as clickable and have the rating bar which can be changed by touches and clicks?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this that. In the `onClick()` Listener of list Item you can `return false` this means that you did not handled the event then the event will be passed to next element the `rating bar`

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing onlist item click change rating bar and on longclick you can display more info in dialog ...